# how to use access database in a AI project or switch it?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, data-science

Is there a way to use a Microsoft Access database in a machine learning project? or a way to migrate to get access to another database more suitable for a machine learning project?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have seen the sqlalchemy-access package? https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-access/ this looks like it might have something for you.